# iOS Accessing Property in parentViewController

Tags: ios, properties, parentviewcontroller, childviewcontroller

My app is crashing when trying to access a method in my parentViewController.  Here is the layout in StoryBoard

[image]

MainViewController = STLMMainViewController (ParentViewController)

Scene1 = STLMTimeDateViewController (ChildViewController)

Here is the code for STLMTimeDateViewController

```
#import "STLMTimeDateViewController.h"
#import "STLMMainViewController.h"

@interface STLMTimeDateViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) STLMMainViewController *stlmMainViewController;
@end


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"The name of the controller %@",self.navigationController.parentViewController);

    stlmMainViewController= (STLMMainViewController *) self.parentViewController;
    [stlmMainViewController locationButtonSelected]; // This is where the App crashes
    NSLog(@"TimeDateController");
}
```

The App Runs, but when STLMMainViewController is called, the app crashes with the following error:

```
2013-02-10 16:33:57.422 MyApp[9120:c07] The name of the controller <STLMMainViewController: 0x83850d0>
2013-02-10 16:33:57.434 MyApp[9120:c07] -[UINavigationController locationButtonSelected]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8371a70
```

If I remove the following line:

```
stlmMainViewController = (STLMMainViewController *) self.parentViewController;
```

and just leave

```
[stlmMainViewController locationButtonSelected];
```

The App runs, no error, but the following method in [STLMMainViewController locationButtonSelected] does not get called (I never see the log):

```
-(void)locationButtonSelected
{
    [LocationButton setSelected:YES];
    [eatDrinkbutton setSelected:NO];
    [timeCalButton setSelected:NO];
    [carButton setSelected:NO];
    [contactButton setSelected:NO];
    NSLog(@"LocationButtonSelected Method");
}
```

All the properties in the locationButtonSelected method and the method itself is declared in .h of STLMMainViewController for public access.

Thanks

Comment: Class reference for UIViewController on apple developer sites say this for parentViewController... 

If the recipient is a child of a container view controller, this property holds the view controller it is contained in. If the recipient has no parent, the value in this property is nil.

Prior to iOS 5.0, if a view did not have a parent view controller and was being presented, the presenting view controller would be returned. On iOS 5, this behavior no longer occurs. Instead, use the presentingViewController property to access the presenting view controller.

Maybe try presentingViewController

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try this:

```
self.stlmMainViewController= (STLMMainViewController *)self.navigationController.parentViewController;
```

(EDIT: actually, as someone else just pointed out, you might want to use presentingViewController instead.)

It looks like you had it right in the log message right before this. You want your navigation controller's parent in this case.

BTW, the reason you don't crash when you delete this line, is because you end up sending the `locationButtonSelected` to nil. That won't crash, but it also won't do anything either.

Comment: That worked beautifully!  Thank you for the code and the explanation @Firoze Bhai.